# Spring Flux: How to configure multiple WebFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm writing a Spring Web Flux application. I have created two WebFilter Component:

**AlphaFilter**

```
class AlphaFilter implement WebFilter {
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        // ....
        // Alpha Filter Configurations
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationFilter**

```
class AuthenticationFilter implement WebFilter {
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        // ....
        // Alpha Filter Configurations
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

I wanted to ensure that `AuthenticationFilter` runs before `AlphaFilter`. How to configure the filters so that `AuthenticationFilter` runs before `AlphaFilter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sagar,

Does [this part of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-filters) answer your question?

> In the WebHandler API, you can use a WebFilter to apply
>   interception-style logic before and after the rest of the processing
>   chain of filters and the target WebHandler. When using the WebFlux
>   Config, registering a WebFilter is as simple as declaring it as a
>   Spring bean and (optionally) expressing precedence by using @Order on
>   the bean declaration or by implementing Ordered.

Comment: Thanks @Stepan. Added @Order(1) annotation of AuthenticationFilter and @Order(2) on AlphaFilter. This helps.